# Is there a way to validate a multipart/form-data request with Joi before the Multer uploads files?

Tags: node.js, express, multer, joi

I'm trying to upload files to my node-js backend service from postman with extra fields like email, username, etc.

I've managed to that with multer, although I want to prevent multer from uploading the data to cloud if the extra fields are missing. So I tried to use Joi to validate the schema with no luck.

Here's the code I tried:

```
const upload = multer({
  storage: new MulterGoogleCloudStorage({
    autoRetry: true,
  })
});

function validateRequest(req: any, res: any, next: () => void) {
    const validator = metadataValidator.validate(req.body);
    if (validator.error) {
      return res.status(400).send("Missing properties.");
    }

    next();
}

router.post('/upload', validateRequest, upload.array("files"), (req, res) => {
 ...
})
```

I understand that the multer middleware must be before the other handlers because it parse the form-data into body. So I must go with that:

```
router.post('/upload', upload.array("files"), validateRequest, (req, res) => {
 ...
})
```

And this works but it already uploads the files even though the request fails on the validateRequest handler. And I'm trying to figure out what should I do.

How can I prevent multer from automatically upload the files if the other fields are not located.

Expected:
I expect to when sending the request without required field it will fail and won't upload files.

Actual:
No matter what I do multer upload files to cloud even when validation fail.

I've also tried:

- [multer how to access multipart form data before uploading files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66286472/multer-how-to-access-multipart-form-data-before-uploading-files)
- [Multer and Joi compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61414037/multer-and-joi-compatibility)

with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be validating `req.body`, and not files, you can call the upload middleware manually, from the route, when the validation middleware is finished:

```
const upload = multer({
  storage: new MulterGoogleCloudStorage({
    autoRetry: true,
  })
}).array("files");


//...


router.post('/upload', validateRequest, (req, res) => {
 
  upload(req, res, function (err) {

    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
      // A Multer error occurred when uploading.
    } else if (err) {
      // An unknown error occurred when uploading.
    }

    // Everything went fine.

    });

});
```

See example from the docs: [Error handling](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#error-handling)